# Fast byte array masking in C#

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, c#-4.0, bit-manipulation

I have a struct with some properties (like `int A1`, `int A2`,...). I store a list of struct as binary in a file.

Now, I'm reading the bytes from file using binary reader into `Buffer` and I want to apply a filter based on  the struct's properties (like `.A1 = 100 & .A2 = 12`).

The performance is very important in my scenario, so I convert the filter criteria to byte array (`Filter`) and then I want to mask `Buffer` with `Filter`. If the result of masking is equal to `Filter`, the `Buffer` will be converted to the struct.

**The question:** What is the fastest way to mask and compare two byte arrays?

**Update:** The `Buffer` size is more than 256 bytes. I'm wondering if there is a better way rather than iterating in each byte of `Buffer` and `Filter`.

Comment: How large is the buffer, and what is the nature of the mask? For example, one common approach is to use unsafe code to treat a byte[] as a ulong*, so that you can process 8 bytes at a time instead of 1 (plus the last few bytes manually if it isn't an exact multiple of 8)

Comment: The buffer size is more than 256 bytes. I'm wondering if there is a better way rather than iterating in each byte of Buffer and Filter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I would usually approach this is with `unsafe` code. You can use the `fixed` keyword to get a `byte[]` as a `long*`, which you can then iterate in 1/8th of the iterations - but using the same bit operations. You will typically have a few bytes left over (from it not being an exact multiple of 8 bytes) - just clean those up manually afterwards.

Comment: Which can cause issues with endianness (file usually has fixed endianness, `long*` has native endianness) and on some architectures unaligned memory access can be slow or even broken.

Comment: @CodeInChaos if you are using bit operations, endianness doesnt usually matter. That is more of a concern when thinking about the value *an an integer*. Just applying a mask: not a problem. The trick is to build the mask using bit ops rather than integer ops, so that the same endianness rules are applied to both. Then you dont need to know which it is.

Answer (score 3):

Try a simple loop with `System.BitConverter.ToInt64()`. Something Like this:

```
byte[] arr1;
byte[] arr2;

for (i = 0; i < arr1.Length; i += 8) 
{
    var P1 = System.BitConverter.ToInt64(arr1, i);
    var P2 = System.BitConverter.ToInt64(arr2, i);

    if((P1 & P2) != P1) //or whatever
        //break the loop if you need to.
}
```

My assumption is that comparing/masking two `Int64`s will be much faster (especially on 64-bit machines) than masking one byte at a time.

Comment: Don't you think that using bit shifting to fill p1 and p2 has better performance?

Comment: @MarcGravell Please see ToInt64 method in: http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/4@0/4@0/DEVDIV_TFS/Dev10/Releases/RTMRel/ndp/clr/src/BCL/System/BitConverter@cs/1305376/BitConverter@cs

Comment: @Amir I'm very familiar with the method (I do a lot of binary protocol work); you haven't said how shifting would help here

Comment: @MarcGravell sorry, you are right. I was thinking of the performance cost of 2 function (Int64) call. But it reduces the iteration to Length/8 (rather than working on a byte).

Comment: @MarcGravell Is there any P/Invoke function to do that faster? I read memcmp is the fastest way to compare 2 byte arrays, but I want to do AND operation on the arrays.

Comment: @Amir only for direct equality compare, which this isn't.

Comment: 1) `BitConverter` is *slow*. Using bitshifts and binary or is faster. 2) It uses native endianness. A file should have fixed endianness. So IMO this is a bad solution.

Answer (score 0):

Once you've got the two arrays - one from reading the file and one from the filter, all you then need is a fast comparison for the arrays. Check out the following postings which are using unsafe or PInvoke methods.

[What is the fastest way to compare two byte arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/627742/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-compare-two-byte-arrays)

[Comparing two byte arrays in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43289/comparing-two-byte-arrays-in-net)

Comment: Thanks, but first of all I want to AND the Filter and Buffer. The posts check for equality.

Comment: Try [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5251355/compare-byte-arrays-with-masking) or [this second example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6868680/how-to-combine-two-image-byte-arrays-together-quickly-utilizing-a-mask-array-i).